# iPhone4+ and safari getting issue of "Blocked a frame with origin http://hostname from accessing a cross-origin frame."

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, satellizer

I'm using this plugin in my application. All the functionality is working fine on all the browsers. But in some of the browsers it is not working. I'm getting this error when I checked in console

```
angular.min.js:107 Error: Blocked a frame with origin "http://hostname.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
     at Error (native)
     at http://hostname.com/js/angular/satellizer.min-5c7877f9d8.js:751:65
     at http://hostname.com/js/angular/angular.min-4fd7d4b889.js:122:65
     at r.$eval (http://hostname.com/js/angular/angular.min-4fd7d4b889.js:133:446)
     at r.$digest (http://hostname.com/js/angular/angular.min-4fd7d4b889.js:131:41)
     at r.$apply (http://hostname.com/js/angular/angular.min-4fd7d4b889.js:134:236)
     at http://hostname.com/js/angular/angular.min-4fd7d4b889.js:97:178
```

I tried to this `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` in angular request headers and also in php side. and also tried to set in apache config file. But it is not working.

Please can you suggest me what can I do to resolve this issue

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636611/how-does-access-control-allow-origin-header-work

Comment: @mplungjan Thanks for your response.. I check the url which you share with me.. But my issue is different, because in my site there is a option to `connect with facebook`. and when any user clicks on this link then a new window opens for facebook login.. At that time I'm getting this issue. So now how can I manage this error. becuase after fill his/her detail on facebook, I'm not getting any response from facebook for that user. :(